# Is it safe/efficient to cancel a c++ thread by writing to an outside variable?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, pthreads

I have a search problem, which I want to parallelize. If one thread has found a solution, I want all other threads to stop. Otherwise, if all threads exit regularly, I know, that there is no solution.

The following code (that demonstrates my cancelling strategy) seems to work, but I'm not sure, if it is safe and the most efficient variant:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <cstdint>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

struct action {
  uint64_t* ii;

  action(uint64_t *ii) : ii(ii) {};

  void operator()() {
    uint64_t k = 0;
    for(; k < *ii; ++k) {
      //do something useful
    }
    cout << "counted to " << k << " in 2 seconds" << endl;
  }
  void cancel() {
    *ii = 0;
  }
};


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  uint64_t ii = 1000000000;
  action a{&ii};
  thread t(a);
  cout << "start sleeping" << endl;
  this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(2000));
  cout << "finished sleeping" << endl;
  a.cancel();
  cout << "cancelled" << endl;
  t.join();
  cout << "joined" << endl;
}
```

Can I be sure, that the value, to which `ii` points, always gets properly reloaded? Is there a more efficient variant, that doesn't require the dereferenciation at every step? I tried to make the upper bound of the loop a member variable, but since the constructor of `thread` copies the instance of `action`, I wouldn't have access to that member later.

Also: If my code is exception safe and does not do I/O (and I am sure, that my platform is Linux), is there a reason not to use `pthread_cancel` on the native thread?

Comment: Very probably you want [std::mutex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) & [std::condition_variable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable)

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no guarantee that this will do anything sensible. The code has one thread reading the value of `ii` and another thread writing to it, without any synchronization. The result is that the behavior of the program is undefined.

I'd just add a flag to the class:

```
std::atomic<bool> time_to_stop;
```

The constructor of `action` should set that to `false`, and the `cancel` member function should set it to `true`. Then change the loop to look at that value:

```
for(; !time_to_stop && k < *ii; ++k)
```

You might, instead, make `ii` atomic. That would work, but it wouldn't be as clear as having a named member to look at.

Comment: Adding an atomic member to a class causes complications, because it makes the default copy-constructor unavailable (``thread`` copies the callable which it gets as a parameter; see also my comment to NathanOliver above)

Comment: @user1512263 - if by that you mean that the compiler doesn't generate a default constructor (I'm not up on those details), fine, just write your own.

Answer (score 1):

First off there is no reason to make `ii` a pointer.  You can have it just as a plain `uint64_t`.

Secondly if you have multiple threads and at least one of them writes to a shared variable then you are going to have to have some sort of synchronization.  In this case you could just use [`std::atomic<uint64_t>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) to get that synchronization.  Otherwise you would have to use a mutex or some sort of memory fence.

Comment: As I already mentioned, the constructor of ``thread`` copies the instance of ``action`` which means, that when I call ``a.cancel()`` the ``action``-instance which ``t`` uses is not modified. This is the reason why ``ii`` is a pointer.

Comment: @user1512263 You can always use references and `std::ref` to pass things by reference to the thread constrcutor

Comment: So accessing references to atomic values is as safe as accessing the atomic values themselves? This code (https://paste2.org/IspZyLpe) should be safe then? It seems at least that some additional checks are performed, because it is slower than the unsafe code.

Comment: @user1512263 Yes it should be safe as `std::atomic` guarantees that only one thread can change it at any one time.